# Creating a globally accessible MySQLi object

Tags: php, constructor, mysqli

I have multiple classes that use **static methods**. These functions connect to the database using

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

where the constants  DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME are database variables defined in a globally accessible file. Recently, my site started becoming slow and after profiling the script I realized that the call to create the object($mysqli) was causing this problem.

Most of my classes extend from mysqli such that

```
public function __construct($user_id) {
    parent::__construct(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $this->retrieve_user_details($user_id);
    $this->check_user_account_type();

}
```

It is to my understanding that static methods **DO NOT** use the __construct method.

Could someone guide me on how I can create the $mysqli object once such that it can be accessed by all **static methods** that require it.

Comment: Do this as static class too.

Comment: @Voitcus what memory/process shall this have. My site has become really slow

Comment: I was thinking what user Jari posted in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach:

Create a singleton class, that can be accessed statically from anywhere.

```
class DBConnector {
    private static $instance ;
    public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $db){
      if (self::$instance){
        exit("Instance on DBConnection already exists.") ;
      }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
      if (!self::$instance){
        self::$instance = new DBConnector(a,b,c,d) ;
      }
      return $instance ;
    }
}
```

An example would be:

```
$mysqli = DBConnector::getInstance() ;
```

Hovewer I suggest using **another solution** as well:

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi(a,b,c,d) ;
```

Then you could pass that object to other classes (constructor)

```
class Shop {
  private $mysqli ;
  public function __construct(MySQLi $mysqli){
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli ;
  }
}

$show = new Shop($mysqli) ;
```

Comment: Thx, We learn something new every day. Could you please elaborate on how I can use this

Comment: Just read on static methods and variables, trust me, it is not complicated at all.

Comment: Am not quite sure that static methods use constructs?

Comment: Singletons contain private constructors. In your singleton example, no mysqli object would be created, as there is no `new mysqli()` request.

Comment: @PhilCross Singletons may contain public constructors as well, they may throw exceptions and so on. In addition, that was just an example.

Comment: @PhilCross thnx for the singleton approach. Have cut valuable secs in my scripts

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on a mysqli singleton:

```
define('SERVER', 'localhost');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DATABASE', 'databaseName');

class mysqliSingleton
{
    private static $instance;
    private $connection;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = new mysqli(SERVER,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new mysqliSingleton();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }


    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        if(method_exists($this->connection, $name))
        {
             return call_user_func_array(array($this->connection, $name), $args);
        } else {
             trigger_error('Unknown Method ' . $name . '()', E_USER_WARNING);
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then request the database connection by calling:

```
$db = mysqliSingleton::init();
```

You can then retrieve the database connection in your own objects:

```
class yourClass
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = mysqliSingleton::init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is the shortest version I could come up with for Bootstrap 3.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        if (hash = window.location.hash) {
            $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
```